# Guess if there is a letter from the alphabet using these clues

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**Not a Meme Clue 1**
What a great choice of images, even though it wasn't a meme!
http://www.wellplannedweb.com/2016/04/why-were-flipping-the-funnel/

**Gibberish Clue 2**
1SIuuWtHZQz7s6otaMof2

**Narrowing my choices Clue 3**
6 + 6

**Edit:**

> Clue 1 is a guide to clue 2.  After the magic of clue 2 is revealed, use clue 3 to guess the letter!
>  This puzzle obviously requires the internet.

**Penguin’s Clue:**

> “One of the other clues is an image, er, maybe not the, er, image, but, er, something nearby put together.” said a Penguin of no meme in particular.

Comment: ... Clue 2 changed ?

Comment: @Rubio Great sir, pardon my error. I made a, *ahem* , public versus private mistake! Zut alors! This comment is now the fourth clue.

Answer (score 1):

> Using the first clue it hints that something will be flipped, then in the second clue it shows us some letters and the only letters that can be flipped into another is ‘w’ and ‘m’. In the final clue, adding the number six in the phone dial numbers is equal to ‘m’ and by another six you will get another ‘m’, so flipping that one it would show how it can flip to ‘w’. So, using the hints the letter **must** be ‘m’. [Sorry if this is hard to understand, it’s my first answer.]